# keep getting all values for B char printed instead of max of all B char values

Tags: arrays, c

```
void getMax(int numOfPitches, char pitchType[], double pitchSpeed[], char pitchToFind, int numOfChars){
    int index = 0;

    for(index = 0; index < numOfPitches; index++){
        if(pitchType[index] == pitchToFind){
            double max = 0.00;
    
            for(int g = 0; g < index; g++){
                if(pitchSpeed[index] > max){
                 max = pitchSpeed[index];
                }
            }
            printf("%.1lf \n", max);
        }   
    }
}
```

```
text file looks like:

S 96.3
B 89.7
S 92.8
H 93.4
B 95.1
B 92.3
B 94.7
S 91.6
S 90.8
S 92.3
S 96.3
H 94.2
S 90.7
B 88.9
B 91.5
S 93.1
H 93.8
```

I've am trying to get the max of all B values, but instead am getting all B float values instead of the max printed out instead of the max value. What is wrong with my code? I thought that it would print the max, but it's printing all B float values.

Comment: user21600183, `double arr[0];` is not valid standard C.  What version of C are you using?

Comment: What should happen if you don't find it?  How are you returning the values found?  `max` usually implies a singular value but you seem to want to find all elements for a given type.  `numOfChars` is not used.

Comment: Edit the question to clarify or provide data but the above is a different question than what you asked initially.  As such it would have been better to submit a new question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> keep getting all values for B char printed instead of max of all B char values

Yes, you do. Look at this part of your code:

```
    if(pitchType[index] == pitchToFind){
        ....
        ....
        ....
        printf("%.1lf \n", max);
    }
```

As you can see, you have an unconditional `printf` **inside** the `if`-statement that checks for type `B`. So you do a print out whenever the type is `B`. You need to move that `printf` to the end of the function, i.e. after the first loop.

Like:

```
for(index = 0; index < numOfPitches; index++){
    if(pitchType[index] == pitchToFind){
        ....
        ....
        ....
    }   
}
printf("%.1lf \n", max);
```

Further, you don't want to set `max` to zero inside the loop. Do it only once and before the loop.

```
double max = 0.00;
for(index = 0; index < numOfPitches; index++){
    if(pitchType[index] == pitchToFind){
        ....
        ....
        ....
    }   
}
printf("%.1lf \n", max);
```

And finally, you don't need nested loops. A single loop will do.

```
double max = 0.00;
for(index = 0; index < numOfPitches; index++){
    if(pitchType[index] == pitchToFind){
         if(pitchSpeed[index] > max){
              max = pitchSpeed[index];
         }
    }   
}
printf("%.1lf \n", max);
```

**End note**

The part

```
    if(pitchType[index] == pitchToFind){
         if(pitchSpeed[index] > max){
              max = pitchSpeed[index];
         }
    }
```

can be written using a single `if` statement like

```
    if(pitchType[index] == pitchToFind && pitchSpeed[index] > max){
         max = pitchSpeed[index];
    }
```

It probably won't make much (if any) difference to the compiled code so that's just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialize `max` outside the (outer) loop otherwise every value will be returned as a `max`.
2. Use a single loop.  There is no reason not to.
3. You haven't told told us what range of values you expect for `pitchSpeed`; if `0` is a valid data point then you cannot use that for the initial value of `max`.
4. Handle the case where search doesn't turn up any results.  In my answer below I use the magic value `-1`.  You could also return a status (`FOUND` / `NOT_FOUND` perhaps) and add `double *max` parameter to return value of interest if `FOUND`.
5. Prefer an `unsigned` type for lengths or counts; otherwise you have to be prepared to handle `numOfPitches < 0`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NOT_FOUND -1

double getMax(unsigned numOfPitches, char pitchType[numOfPitches], double pitchSpeed[numOfPitches], char pitchToFind) {
    double *max = NULL;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < numOfPitches; i++)
        if(
            pitchType[i] == pitchToFind &&
            (!max || *max < pitchSpeed[i])
        )
                max = &pitchSpeed[i];
    return max ? *max : NOT_FOUND;
}

int main() {
    double max = getMax(17,
        "SBSHBBBSSSSHSBBSH",
        (double []) { 96.3,89.7,92.8,93.4,95.1,92.3,94.7,91.6,90.8,92.3,96.3,94.2,90.7,88.9,91.5,93.1,93.8},
        'B'
    );
    printf("%g\n", max);
}
```

and example output:

```
95.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring `max` and initializing it to zero at each iteration where `pitchType[index] == pitchToFind` will print all values of `b` because they all will be greater than 0.00, declare and initialize `max` somewhere else